# Is there a working code example of webUSB for an Arduino Uno R3 using the CH340 driver?

Tags: arduino, webusb

In a web page am able to find the device, but when I attempt to open the connection with .open() I get "access denied".
Through research I came across the winUsb driver, which allows me to open a connection to the device. Unfortunately, when I use that driver that I can no longer use the Arduino IDE to communicate with the device. It does not list the port as being available.
In the Windows device manager the device moves under Universal Serial Bus devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For devices using the CH340 my recommendation is to use the Web Serial API instead of the WebUSB API. This will leverage the CH340 driver that is already installed and is used by the Arduino IDE, so there won't be any conflicts when trying to access the device with either application.

See [web.dev/serial](https://web.dev/serial/) for some documentation on how to use the API.

Comment: Great thanks I'll check it out

Comment: unfortunately serial API does not support by Android browsers :(